# How does scala handle a class extends a class with a generic of itself?

Tags: scala, compilation

```
class Person extends Friend[Person]
```

How does Person been explained while it extends a Friend[Person] class ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please elaborate and explain what it is you do not understand.

Answer (score 3):

If `class A extends B[A]`, class `A` appears as a *type constructor parameter* of itself. There is nothing special about this reappearance, i.e. it's no different from a `class A extends B[C]`.

For example, if `B` was trait `Ordered`:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) extends Ordered[Person] {
  // in method `compare(that: A)` of Ordered, type `A` is replaced with `Person`
  def compare(that: Person): Int = {
    val i = this.name compare that.name
    if (i != 0) i else this.age compare that.age
  }
}
```